# how can i pattern match on runtime class in scala

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a snippet of code like this:

```
override def getOption[T: TypeTag: ClassTag](path: String): Option[T] = {
  implicitly[scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]].toString() match {
    case "java.lang.String" => HandleBlank(super.getOption[String](path)).asInstanceOf[Option[T]]
    case _ => super.getOption[T](path)
  }
}
```

I assume there must be a better way to do this than matching by string, but tried a few things (like `classOf[String]`) and can't seem to find something that works.

For context, getOption (in the superclass that we are trying to override) gets an Option value from a json4s AST JValue object

```
def getOption[T: TypeTag: ClassTag](path: String): Option[T] = Try(getJValue(path).extract[T]).toOption

def getJValue(path: String): JValue = {
  path.split('.').foldLeft(value)((a, b) => a \ b) match {
    case JNull => JNothing
    case j     => j
  }
}
```

The idea is that I want to shim it so that for only String types of that method, we want to handle blank strings in a special way.

Comment: This might be easier to answer if we knew exactly what `getOption` was meant to do.  There are better ways than to match against the string, but they won't cover all cases. The implicit `TypeTag` currently isn't being used, it seems.

Comment: i added more context. The TypeTag stuff is to work w/ the underlying json4s extract method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do direct equality tests between `ClassTag`s like this:

```
override def getOption[T: TypeTag: ClassTag](path: String): Option[T] = {
  // not required, just nicer to write classTag[T] vs. implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
  import reflect.classTag
  classTag[T] match {
    case strTag if strTag == classTag[String] => HandleBlank(super.getOption[String](path)).asInstanceOf[Option[T]]
    case _ => super.getOption[T](path)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One common trick is to put the value you want to compare with into a local variable or a field:

```
import scala.reflect.classTag

val StringTag = classTag[String]

override def getOption[T: TypeTag: ClassTag](path: String): Option[T] = {
  classTag[T] match {
    case StringTag => ...
    case _ => ...
  }
}
```

Note that the name should start with a capital letter, otherwise `case stringTag` will just bind a fresh variable (though you can surround `stringTag` with ` to fix this).